# Auto update page after certain interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

[image]I am having a website where people can add posts and comments like any social media.

Everything is working great except auto update feature: what I want is to automatically update the page after every 20 seconds.

By updating the page I mean that it automatically shows the newly added posts and comments to the page.

I can do this by ajax load function like

```
$('#divid').load("page.php #divid");
```

But in this case there is a problem: when any user is typing something and if then the div is reloaded, the user text is lost; what if I am having is infinite scroll  load function that causes the site to load the items again and again.

I think this is possible as many sites does this thing, similar like gmail shows us new emails without reloading the div.

Comment: "if the div is reloaded the user text is lost" - then place the text box out of this div?

Comment: there are more than 10 posts per div and post has a text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is prepend the new posts to the top of your page instead of reloading all content.

An example of the AJAX response should be like this:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "title": "Post Title",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "1235",
            "title": "Post Title",
            ...
        }
    ],
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": "12345678",
            "post_id": "1112",
            "content": "foo",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

The `posts` array should be prepended to page. Each item of the `comments` array should be appended to the corresponding post's *comments* section.

Comment: and what should i do with comments

Comment: reload them via ajax also